# passing a int** to a C routine using JNA

Tags: java, arrays, native, jna

I'm having in my java program a int[][] that stores some data I want to compute (alter)
in a C routine. But I can't figure out how to pass the "pointer to pointer to int" to the
C code which declares a f(int sz, int** structure). Any idea?

Thanks,
Luc.d

Comment: Depends on the data layout expected by the native code.  "int**" appears to map to a contiguous block of "int*", but it might not.

In any case, you can't pass a Java multi-dimensional array directly to native code.  JNA only allows mapping from a one-dimensional primitive array into a native block of contiguous memory.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is question is tagged JNA,
[Similar Example in JNA docs](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/ByRefArguments.md)

```
// Original C declaration
void allocate_buffer(char **bufp, int* lenp);

// Equivalent JNA mapping
 void allocate_buffer(PointerByReference bufp, IntByReference lenp);

// Usage
PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();
IntByReference iref = new IntByReference();
lib.allocate_buffer(pref, iref);
Pointer p = pref.getValue();
byte[] buffer = p.getByteArray(0, iref.getValue());
```

Isn't this what you are looking for ? you use PointerByReference when there is a Pointer to a Pointer.

Comment: Well actually JNA permits to capture a returned type**, but not to pass one. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jnistring.html#multi) example might come in handy :)